# framework not found FirebaseInstanceID in Xcode

Tags: xcode, cocoapods

Step to reproduce.

1. I have added all the pod frameworks into my cordova project using XCode, after added, I don't know why the frameworks are whiten as this [picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0q1Sj.png).
2. So I start to build the project again, the first error said framework not found FirebaseInstallation, I thought the whiten framework is not valid, so I manually add the framework from my [frameworks folder](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tYwBj.png) which is downloaded from https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks and finally become the normal yellow icon.
3. I rebuild the project, this time the error is framework not found FirebaseCoreDiagnostics. Therefore, I repeat step 2 to add in the framework manually and compile again.
4. This time the error is also framework not found but it is FirebaseInstanceID. As you can see from my Pods folder above, there is no FirebaseInstanceID framework that I can manually add into my project. I have search online, there is no single file named FirebaseInstanceID.framework exist on the internet. Where can I download it actually?

Furthermore, is it the right way to manually add in all the pod frameworks into my project to solve the error? How can solve this kind of framework not found issue in Xcode? Thanks for any comment.

Answer (score 0):

`FirebaseInstanceID.framework` is available in several of the folders from the download https://firebase.google.com/docs/ios/setup#frameworks, including `FirebaseMessaging`.

Comment: The link is exactly where I download all the framework from but the file did not include FirebaseInstanceID.framework.

Comment: Please my answer carefully and check again.  FirebaseInstanceID.framework is in a different folder from the previous release.

Comment: Thanks, found it. It is inside the folder "FirebaseMLVision".

Comment: In adding FirebaseMessagerBinary via Carthage, I had do include FirebaseMLVisionBinary for FirebaseInstanceID.framework to appear in my build directory. Once I added this and Protobuf.framework, the project linked again. This is not clear in the documentation.