# Framework not found FirebaseInstanceID on Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode, firebase

I get below error from Xcode. Tried many solutions available on Internet but of no use.

```
  ld: framework not found FirebaseInstanceID
```

Solutions I tried:

1. https://stackoverflow.com/a/31298214/10182352
2. [framework not found FirebaseInstanceID in Xcode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60431212/framework-not-found-firebaseinstanceid-in-xcode)
3. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52386172/10182352

Tried deleting Podfile.lock and Podfile and initiated again by:

```
pod init
pod install
pod update
```

My Podfile looks like:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

# CocoaPods analytics sends network stats synchronously affecting flutter build latency.
ENV['COCOAPODS_DISABLE_STATS'] = 'true'    
project 'Runner', {
  'Debug' => :debug,
  'Profile' => :release,
  'Release' => :release,
}

def parse_KV_file(file, separator='=')
  file_abs_path = File.expand_path(file)
  if !File.exists? file_abs_path
    return [];
  end
  generated_key_values = {}
  skip_line_start_symbols = ["#", "/"]
  File.foreach(file_abs_path) do |line|
    next if skip_line_start_symbols.any? { |symbol| line =~ /^\s*#{symbol}/ }
    plugin = line.split(pattern=separator)
    if plugin.length == 2
      podname = plugin[0].strip()
      path = plugin[1].strip()
      podpath = File.expand_path("#{path}", file_abs_path)
      generated_key_values[podname] = podpath
    else
      puts "Invalid plugin specification: #{line}"
    end
  end
  generated_key_values
end

target 'Runner' do
  use_frameworks!
  use_modular_headers!
  # Flutter Pod
  copied_flutter_dir = File.join(__dir__, 'Flutter')
  copied_framework_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Flutter.framework')
  copied_podspec_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Flutter.podspec')
  unless File.exist?(copied_framework_path) && File.exist?(copied_podspec_path)
    # Copy Flutter.framework and Flutter.podspec to Flutter/ to have something to link against if the xcode backend script has not run yet.
    # That script will copy the correct debug/profile/release version of the framework based on the currently selected Xcode configuration.
    # CocoaPods will not embed the framework on pod install (before any build phases can generate) if the dylib does not exist.

    generated_xcode_build_settings_path = File.join(copied_flutter_dir, 'Generated.xcconfig')
    unless File.exist?(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
      raise "Generated.xcconfig must exist. If you're running pod install manually, make sure flutter pub get is executed first"
    end
    generated_xcode_build_settings = parse_KV_file(generated_xcode_build_settings_path)
    cached_framework_dir = generated_xcode_build_settings['FLUTTER_FRAMEWORK_DIR'];

    unless File.exist?(copied_framework_path)
      FileUtils.cp_r(File.join(cached_framework_dir, 'Flutter.framework'), copied_flutter_dir)
    end
    unless File.exist?(copied_podspec_path)
      FileUtils.cp(File.join(cached_framework_dir, 'Flutter.podspec'), copied_flutter_dir)
    end
  end

  # Keep pod path relative so it can be checked into Podfile.lock.
  pod 'Flutter', :path => 'Flutter'

  # Plugin Pods

  # Prepare symlinks folder. We use symlinks to avoid having Podfile.lock
  # referring to absolute paths on developers' machines.
  system('rm -rf .symlinks')
  system('mkdir -p .symlinks/plugins')
  plugin_pods = parse_KV_file('../.flutter-plugins')
  plugin_pods.each do |name, path|
    symlink = File.join('.symlinks', 'plugins', name)
    File.symlink(path, symlink)
    pod name, :path => File.join(symlink, 'ios')
  end
end

# Prevent Cocoapods from embedding a second Flutter framework and causing an error with the new Xcode build system.
install! 'cocoapods', :disable_input_output_paths => true

post_install do |installer|
  installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
    target.build_configurations.each do |config|
      config.build_settings['ENABLE_BITCODE'] = 'NO'
    end
  end
end

pod 'FirebaseCore'
pod 'Firebase/Analytics'
pod 'Firebase/Performance'
pod 'Crashlytics', '~> 3.12.0'
pod 'GoogleSignIn', '~> 4.4.0'
```

[image: Error from XCode]

I have also make sure that I have opened `xcodeworkspace` not `xcodeproject`.

For more clarification, I have removed this framework from my `Frameworks` tab search paths too.

[image: Removed FirebaseInstanceID framework]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After 12 hours of constantly going through the DOCs of Firebase and implementing every answers on Stack Overflow I managed to eradicate this error. Below steps are what I did for this:

1. The framework mentioned above isn't included in the PODs which I have installed. So you need to explicitly download the framework from https://firebase.google.com/download/ios
2. Once the SDK is downloaded, firstly clear the DerivedData by going to Xcode -> Preferences -> Locations -> Derived Data. Move into that directory and delete the DerivedData folder.
3. Delete Podfile.lock and Pods folder and do `pod init` and `pod install`.
4. Open XCode and copy the path of framework SDK that you downloaded. For me it is: `/user/Downloads/Firebase/FirebaseMessaging/FirebaseInstanceID.xcframework/ios-i386_x86_64-simulator` and copy this in `Framework Search Paths` which is under `Build Settings`.
5. Drag and drop the folder named `FirebaseInstanceID.framework` into Frameworks list as shown in second image of the question(left side).

Comment: But, if we have installed other pods such as NVActivityIndicator etc, what will happen, for me it threw an error

Comment: Other pods will remain unaffected as you're only setting the path for this particular framework, rest all frameworks will be unaffected.

Answer (score 22):

@Paul your answer was spotless. I managed to eradicate this annoying problem following your suggestion:

1. Open MyRockingApp.xcodeproj
2. Linking -> Other Linker Flags -> Debug/Release
3. Delete -framework "FirebaseInstanceID"

Thank you very much!

Comment: This is the correct solution. Works. 

Also FirebaseInstanceID was deprecated.

Comment: For a littler more clarity go to: `Targets` > `Build Settings` > In the search box in the upper right corner enter `FirebaseInstanceID` > then click the down arrow to open `Other Linker Flags` > **Debug** > double click the right side where it says **-ObjC** > when the list appears, select/click/highlight `FirebaseInstanceID` and `-framework` right above it > click the minus sign on the bottom. Do it for **Release** too because it's in both places. FYI if you don't delete the `-framework` along with it your app won't build https://stackoverflow.com/a/69888126/4833705

Answer (score 2):

**Remove -l"FirebaseInstanceID" from linker list.
[Target/Build Settings/Linking/Other linker flags].**
When updating the pod, it removed the library, but did not remove key from  target.linker.list. After manual deletion pod.update not returns it back.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect the Xcode project has a lingering reference to FirebaseInstanceID. The latest versions of the pods listed do not need it.

It should work to remove references to FirebaseInstanceID from the Xcode project.

Comment: FirebaseInstanceID framework wasn't available on the frameworks that I listed on my Podfile. So I have to download whole SDK and it was present in different other frameworks like FirebaseMessaging and others. I fixed this BTW.

Answer (score 0):

```
pod deintegrate
pod install
```

Resolved my problem.