# ld: -framework not found

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase

I followed this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62716083/4833705) and deleted a reference to FirebaseInstanceId that seemed to be left over from when I removed the pod. Now when I build I get the error:

> ld: -framework not found
>
> clang: error: linker command failed
> with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

For a little more clarity:

`Targets` > `Build Settings` > `Linker Flags` > `Debug` & `Release` (separately) > double clicked the right side where it says -ObjC > select/click/highlight `FirebaseInstanceID >` clicked the minus sign on the bottom.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Turns out when I deleted `FirebaseInstanceID` I was supposed to delete the `-framework` right above it too.

Here is a pic of the correct way to do it. I'm going to delete `GoogleInterchangeUtilities` and the `-framework` right above it. Once I press the minus sign at the bottom they will both disappear

[image]